# Как вместить spinner в заданую ширину?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

У меня есть `Spinner` и я никак не могу вместить его в 300sp! Ему, по смыслу, и стольки будет многовато, но он на отрез не влазит! Справа срезает экран и не помещается... Что делать?

Вот код .xml файла:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300sp"
    android:layout_height="360sp"
    android:layout_margin="3sp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_forms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOK_wordsadd"
    android:layout_width="300sp"
    android:layout_height="40sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3sp"
    android:background="@drawable/button1"
    android:text="Готово" />
```

И фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `sp` - для текста. Для размеров вьюшек надо пользовать `dp`. И таки не понятно зачем вам это? Чем не устраивает `match_parent`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, с ``match_parent`` нельзя, там другие вьюшки будут. А ``dp`` сейчас поменяю.

Comment: Ну так если у вас экран меньше `300dp`, то вы **никак** не сможете вместить в него что-то, больше размера экрана не обрезав это...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а нельзя никак уменьшить, чтобы было красиво?)

Comment: "чтобы было красиво?" - это очень субъективно. Если текст в спиннере будет оч. длинный, то его в любом случае обрежет... Кроме `match_parent` сделать ничего не выйдет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, текст не длинный. Сама иконка не влазит.

Comment: Родительскому элементу установите `match_parent` и всё влезет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, теперь окно "сдвинулось" и оно размером, чуть больше текста. Но уже все влезло :).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, киньте в ответ, про ``match_parent``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp` - для текста. Для размеров вьюшек надо пользовать `dp`. Для того, чтобы не вылезало за границы экрана надо проставить ширину равной `match_parent`